# Need Help About Api Routing

Tags: api, url, routes, attributes

I need some helps about api routing. There is my codes:

WebApiConfig.cs;

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{no}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, no = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

RouteConfig.cs;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");            

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name:"UserControl",
            url:"{controller}/"
            );
    }
```

Global.asax.cs;

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

and this is my api;

```
 public object GetParselNo(int id, int no)
    {
        List<TapuParselModel> parselList = TapuModule.GetParselListFromMahalleAndAdaTapuKod(id, no.ToString());

        List<string> parselNoList = parselList.Select(x => x.ParselNo).ToList<string>();
        parselNoList = parselNoList.OrderBy(x => x, new AlphanumComparator()).ToList();

        var jsonResult = SConvert.SerializeJSON(parselNoList);

        return jsonResult;


    }
```

Now it's working like this. But the api url is;
http://localhost:55591/Api/TapuParselApi/GetParselNo/146436/80

I want to see URL like ;
http://localhost:55591/Api/TapuParselApi/GetParselNo/**MahalleId**/146436/**AdaNo**/80

it means MahalleId=146436 and AdaNo=80. I tried route attribute on my ApiController. But this time Global.asax.cs thow exception. Then tried to delete row in Global.asax.cs; this time api isn't working. What should i do?? Anyone know? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found easylier way too while searching. And I wanted share this way with all;

It's so simple. Just add your Web.config

```
<handlers>
  **<remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />**
</handlers>
```

So you don't need change your wep api route... Thank you all...It solved..

Answer (score 0):

If using web api 2, then attribute routing makes this pretty easy.

```
[Route("Api/TapuParselApi/GetParselNo/MahalleId/{id}/AdaNo/{no}")]
public object GetParselNo(int id, int no) { ... }
```

If not, you can add this route into your web api route config before the default route:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "GetParselNo",
        routeTemplate: "api/TapuParselApi/GetParselNo/MahalleId/{id}/AdaNo/{no}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, no = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```